# Strange crash when presenting view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit

I get a strange crash when presenting a modal view controller on iOS 7, it only happens on iPhone 5C I haven't been able to repro on the iPhone 5 or 5s. I've attached the crash log below, as well as the code that presents the view controller.  I used the presenting view controller as the transitioning delegate to have a custom fade in effect.  Please let me know if you need any more information about this.

Code to present:

```
PresentedViewController *vc = [[PresentedViewController alloc] init];
vc.transitioningDelegate = self;
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Crash Log:

```
Incident Identifier: 161D4D3E-146F-4CC6-A13C-66BF6305942F
CrashReporter Key:   DCFCE3DE-6815-4EA6-85A5-AD5006E34125
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,3
Process:         AppName [10236]
Path:            /Users/USER/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:      com.appname
Version:         4
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2014-09-02T20:31:52Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xb006dbcc
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: isHeaderFlaggedFPO

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x395c277a lookUpImpOrForward + 46
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x395bb02b _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 32
2   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x395badf9 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 22
3   CoreUI                               0x3339bd0d -[CUIStructuredThemeStore renditionWithKey:] + 1050
4   CoreUI                               0x333a50af -[CUINamedImage _renditionForSpecificKey:] + 168
5   CoreUI                               0x333a50fd -[CUINamedImage image] + 18
6   UIKit                                0x31a02c01 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:] + 258
7   UIKit                                0x31a02af7 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:] + 36
8   UIKit                                0x31a02acd -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:subtype:] + 42
9   UIKit                                0x31a02a9b -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:idiom:] + 44
10  UIKit                                0x31d47ab1 -[UIImageNibPlaceholder initWithCoder:] + 286
11  UIKit                                0x31ddd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 738
12  UIKit                                0x31ddceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 88
13  UIKit                                0x31cb61db -[UIImageView initWithCoder:] + 88
14  UIKit                                0x31ddd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 738
15  UIKit                                0x31ddd179 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 642
16  UIKit                                0x31ddceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 88
17  UIKit                                0x31c7996d -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 650
18  UIKit                                0x31ddd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 738
19  UIKit                                0x31ddd179 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 642
20  UIKit                                0x31ddceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 88
21  UIKit                                0x31c7996d -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 650
22  UIKit                                0x31ddd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 738
23  UIKit                                0x31ddceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 88
24  UIKit                                0x31d46c1f -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 148
25  UIKit                                0x31ddd1d9 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 738
26  UIKit                                0x31ddd179 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 642
27  UIKit                                0x31ddceef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 88
28  UIKit                                0x31d463f5 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 886
29  UIKit                                0x31ca80fb -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 232
30  UIKit                                0x31b09b59 -[UIViewController loadView] + 90
31  UIKit                                0x319eb79d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 70
32  UIKit                                0x319eb719 -[UIViewController view] + 22
33  UIKit                                0x31a955cf -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 24
34  UIKit                                0x31ad1c97 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 248
35  UIKit                                0x31ad05c5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2058
36  UIKit                                0x31acf631 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4674
37  AppName                              0x000c4b9d -[PresentingViewController storePurchaseSuccessWithType:andUser:] (PresentingViewController.m:221)
38  AppName                              0x000c5179 __54-[PresentingViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]_block_invoke (PresentingViewController.m:245)
39  AppName                              0x00225687 -[RACSubscriber sendNext:] (RACSubscriber.m:73)
40  AppName                              0x0020d447 -[RACPassthroughSubscriber sendNext:] (RACPassthroughSubscriber.m:74)
41  AppName                              0x00225687 -[RACSubscriber sendNext:] (RACSubscriber.m:73)
42  AppName                              0x0020eda1 __29-[RACReturnSignal subscribe:]_block_invoke (RACReturnSignal.m:85)
43  AppName                              0x00225f15 -[RACSubscriptionScheduler schedule:] (RACSubscriptionScheduler.m:40)
44  AppName                              0x0020ed37 -[RACReturnSignal subscribe:] (RACReturnSignal.m:84)
45  AppName                              0x00220aa5 -[RACSignal(Subscription) subscribeNext:error:completed:] (RACSignal.m:302)
46  AppName                              0x0021f2df __29-[RACSignal(RACStream) bind:]_block_invoke76 (RACSignal.m:139)
47  AppName                              0x0021f521 __29-[RACSignal(RACStream) bind:]_block_invoke113 (RACSignal.m:165)
48  AppName                              0x00225687 -[RACSubscriber sendNext:] (RACSubscriber.m:73)
49  AppName                              0x0020d447 -[RACPassthroughSubscriber sendNext:] (RACPassthroughSubscriber.m:74)
50  AppName                              0x0020d447 -[RACPassthroughSubscriber sendNext:] (RACPassthroughSubscriber.m:74)
51  AppName                              0x00224ccd -[RACSubject enumerateSubscribersUsingBlock:] (RACSubject.m:85)
52  AppName                              0x00224dad -[RACSubject sendNext:] (RACSubject.m:92)
53  AppName                              0x0020e65d -[RACReplaySubject sendNext:] (RACReplaySubject.m:89)
54  AppName                              0x0008fa3d __71-[AFURLConnectionOperation(RACSupport) rac_overrideHTTPCompletionBlock]_block_invoke (AFURLConnectionOperation+RACSupport.m:42)
55  libdispatch.dylib                    0x39aa40c3 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
56  libdispatch.dylib                    0x39aa40af _dispatch_client_callout + 20
57  libdispatch.dylib                    0x39aa69a9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 266
58  CoreFoundation                       0x2f22d5b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 6
59  CoreFoundation                       0x2f22be7d __CFRunLoopRun + 1306
60  CoreFoundation                       0x2f196471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
61  CoreFoundation                       0x2f196253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
62  GraphicsServices                     0x33ed02eb GSEventRunModal + 136
63  UIKit                                0x31a4b845 UIApplicationMain + 1134
64  AppName                              0x000ab367 main (main.m:16)
65  libdyld.dylib                        0x39ab8ab7 start + 0
```

Comment: You ever figure this out or work around it?  I'm seeing the same thing...